# How to Retrieve Knowledge Validation Status Picklist custom values?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, lightning-knowledge

Validation Status is a standard picklist available in Lightning Knowledge (Knowledge_kav), however the field metadata is not available in Knowledge Settings or Knowledge Object. I even tried Standard value Set and its not available there as well.

I want to retrieve this field with Picklist values and deploy to another org via metadata. Please let me know if you have any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough if you create one in a scratch org it will be tracked as a StandardValueSet, but does not work with a metadata retrieve from a standard sandbox.

```
=== Source Status
STATE       FULL NAME                     TYPE              PROJECT PATH
──────────  ────────────────────────────  ────────────────  ────────────
Remote Add  KnowledgeValidationStatus     StandardValueSet
```

So I assume that this is not yet supported, but potentially a part of the ExpandedSourceTracking beta specific to scratch orgs.